# Getting the x of the next entry on the atribute table

Tags: qgis

I've been struggling for the past hours with this situation, I need to get the X and Y coordinates of the next entry of the atribute table like the image shows, is there any tool or function in QGIS that I can use?

Or do I have to use Excel or make a mini program of my own to do it? I've tried the "$X_at" and some other functions and nothing.

[image: Question]

Comment: Are your entity line ? and is xFin the x coordinate of the last vertices of the courant line ?

Comment: No they are points. But i got these points by spliting a line in segments of 5m so if it is easier I can go back to the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a numeric field, called "id." Use the Field Calculator to fill the "id" field with row number values.

[image]

Install the refFunctions plugin.

Use the Field Calculator to update "xFin" with "Xini" value from the next row down, using this expression:

```
 dbvalue( 'Vertices_5m', 'Xini', 'id', @row_number+1 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Mind using *SpatiaLite* SQL?

With your line segment layer loaded

- open the `<QGIS> | Database | DB Manager...`

  - expand `Virtual Layers | Project Layers` in the left panel
  - open a new `SQL Window` (2nd button from left, top row)
  - paste and run (`Execute`)

    ```
    SELECT <field_name_1>,
           ...,
           <field_name_n>,
           ST_X(ST_StartPoint(geometry)) AS "Xini",
           ST_X(ST_EndPoint(geometry)) AS " xFin",
           ST_Y(ST_StartPoint(geometry)) AS " Yini",
           ST_Y(ST_EndPoint(geometry)) AS " yFin",
           geometry
    FROM <line_segment_layer_name>;
    ```
  - activate `Add as new layer...`

    - choose name, and `geometry` as geometry column
- `<Layer_context> | Save features as...` to export as e.g. *shapefile*

This will select all columns (fields) you specify (`<field_name_n>`) from that layer, plus the X & Y components of the start and end point of your line segments (and the line `geometry`s themselves) into a new (temporary) layer.

Answer (score 0):

if you have point that divide a line in 5m segment then two consecutive point will have the x coordinate of the first and last vertices of the segment they define.

So if you could go back to the segment you could use the "$X_at" ( `$x_at(0)` for the first vertice and `$x_at(-1)` for the last) to get your coordinate